# Hide pg_catalogs in postgreSQL from end users

Tags: postgresql

When users are connecting to PostgreSQL DB using GUI tools, they are able to see pg_catalog in user created database like `testdb`

Can we hide system catalogs from end user and show them only testdb and their schema(user created schema)? As i have checked there is no option in PostgreSQL like in oracle below.

```
ALTER SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME SET TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_NAME;
```

but yes, we can create objects which will be in schema_name to another tablespace but we can't give tablespace at schema level in PostgreSQL.

`create table tablename (int id) tablespace tablespacename;`

also end user firing query on db from gui tool, they are getting table from pg_catalog and information_schema also. can we hide this? i know they are not using specific schema name in where clause in the query.

Comment: No, you cannot hide the system catalogs without breaking the system, and this is not related to tablespaces at all. You probably don't need a tablespace.

Comment: What is the problem with the end user being able to access the `information_schema`?  If you are comparing that to Oracle, do you also disable access to `all_tables`  and similar views there?

Comment: Actually they want all system catalog tables should be in separate tablespace and all user created tables in seprate tablespace so we have suggested them to                     ` ` `                                                                                                                           
 ALTER DATABASE SET test DEFAULT TABLESPACE pg_default  ` ` `   and while creating new tables use tablespace which you want to store your user created tablespace rather than pg_default